# initState() method of first activity is not initializing after taking popback stack from the aother activity

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-state

I am working on flutter application where I am using 3 screens.

`MainActivity` open to `ActivityClass1` and `ActivityClass1` will open `ActivityClass2`. Now when I am taking `Navigator.pop(context),` from ActivityClass2 it will shows ActivityClass1 from the stack. But this time I need to take `initState()` of `ActivityClass1` as I need to refresh few data on `ActivityClass1`.

Is there any way to call `initState()` of `ActivityClass1` which also maintain my stack for `MainActivity` -> `ActivityClass1`?
I have also tried for `Navigator.of(context).pushAndRemoveUntil(` instead of using `Navigator.pop(context),` on `ActivityClass2` but this will clears my stack.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Navigator.push` returns a `Future` when the `MaterialPageRoute` passed into it is resolved. You could await that `Future` to know when some other view has popped back to it.

Example,

```dart
Navigator.of(context).push(MaterialPageRoute(
  builder: 
    (context) => NewView(),
  ),
).then((_) {
  // Call setState() here or handle this appropriately
});
```

So now when I am coming back to my Activity Class1 this method will help to take any action while comming back to screen by just using `Navigator.pop(context),`.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to start the initial state of the screen again, you can use pushReplacement instead of Pop() when you want to back.
It works for me:

Use pushReplacement to go to ActivityClass2 and to back to ActivityClass1

> ActivityClass2 -> ActivityClass1

```
Navigator.pushReplacement(
  context,
  MaterialPageRoute(
    builder: (context) => ActivityClass1(),
  ),
);
```

Comment: I have tried the same solution but this can create a stack like MainActivity() -> Screen1 -> Screen1. So now when I press back from screen1 it will pop again to Screen1.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `Navigator.of(context).pop`, use:

```
Navigator.push(
  context,
  MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => SecondRoute()),
);
```

Comment: If I will use the `Navigator.push` call again then this screen will also be added to my stack, so now if I'll press back this will show me like Screen1 -> Screen2 -> Screen1 -> MainActivity. Which is the wrong flow. I need something where it works as screen1 -> MainActivity in my stack after pressing back from screen2.

Comment: Use pushReplacement